# Cake with ganache on top going to the freezer

Tags: freezing

I’ll pour the ganache over the cake, then freeze the cake with the ganache on top. Will it freeze ok together?

Answer (score 1):

Freezing a cake with ganache should be fine.
You can read more about freezing a cake with ganache here:
https://www.cakecentral.com/forum/t/680186/can-i-freeze-a-cake-covered-in-ganache